# Additional Entity ID for networking instead of general EID?

Tags: networking, entity-component

http://t-machine.org/index.php/2015/06/09/entity-ids-how-big-using-uuids-or-not-why-etc/

I see this one article that proposes specific IDs just for the networking side of the game. If you are already employing IDs for your entities, is there any benefit on adding IDs just for client-server communication instead of reusing the original local ID (one that you know is not subject to collisions)?

Answer (score 1):

An UUID takes up 128 bits.

Your own ID can be as small as `ceil(log_2(n))` bits; where n is the number of entities you want to distinguish between.

Getting the entity from the UUID requires a hashmap. A cleverly constructed ID system will let you simply index into an array instead, which is slightly faster.

You can also embed some type information in the ID usually by assigning ranges to each type. This lets you avoid a downcast/typecheck in the network code because you can have separate containers for each type.